# Unable to migrate Wordpress from one server to another

Tags: wordpress, backup, database-backups

I am trying to migrate my old website into new cloud server but I am unable to do that. I check different plugin but still at the end It will stuck.

I also tried wp all in one migration but It stuck in the **restore database**.

Any one know how to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the console error you get? Isnt there a server problem, do you have free memory space or writable space? This may occur the problem. I use all in one wp migration too but I have had this problem just a few times and mainly because of disc scape or just some error and when I tried again it worked. Did you try duplicator aswell? Same problem there?

Comment: My whole back is around 2 GB, and I boot the disk with 50 GB storage

Comment: Duplicator has size restriction

Comment: Do you have any console errors when you are stuck?

Comment: There is no console error, It start processing and stop there, But when I try the same thing on my local machine. It works fine

Comment: I tried again its giving me 404 and 500 Request, How to fix this

Comment: Error 500 is internal server error. So there is probably problem with your server. Try to contact your hosting provider.

Comment: Isn't it anything to do with database connection (error)? Everything (db, user, pw) is set correctly?

Comment: Yes All is correct

Comment: Its on google cloud @LuboMasura